# Extract value from XML

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, extract-value

I am using this query to extract the value from the XML

```sql
SELECT extractvalue(column_value, '/TransactionLimitDTO/idTxn') "TxnId"
FROM TABLE(XMLSequence(XMLType(mg.limits)
            .extract('/ModifyTransactionLimitRequestDTO/transactionLimit/TransactionLimitDTO'))) t,Mstgloballimitspackage mg
```

But, I'm getting an error:

> ORA-00904: "MG"."LIMITS": invalid identifier

Could you please tell me how can I resolve this?

I tried this:

```sql
 SELECT extractvalue(column_value, '/TransactionLimitDTO/idTxn') "TxnId"
 FROM TABLE(XMLSequence(XMLType(select mg.limits from Mstgloballimitspackage mg)
                          .extract('/ModifyTransactionLimitRequestDTO/transactionLimit/TransactionLimitDTO'))) t
```

but this is also not working.

When I put a complete XML file in the place of `mg.limits` I get a *too long string literal as a argument* error.

It is working whenever I place a small piece of XML in the place of `mg.limits`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```sql
 SELECT extractvalue(t.column_value, '/TransactionLimitDTO/idTxn') "TxnId"
     FROM Mstgloballimitspackage mg,
          TABLE(XMLSequence(XMLType(mg.limits,'')
                            .extract('/ModifyTransactionLimitRequestDTO/transactionLimit/TransactionLimitDTO'))) t
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you could explain _why_ this works; it will help people who come to this question in the future.